# Blocking electro-magnetic waves between two near field antennas

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-fields, induction

Its been a while since I studied physics, so pardon my ignorance.

I have two near field antennas. The range of the antennas is about 2-3 cm. I am looking for a way where I can block and unblock the communication between them.

One of the way that I tried is to place a flat tightly woven wire and if I short the two ends of the wire, I was able to block the communication. My assumption is that it is effectively changing the frequency of the signal and thus blocking the signal. Is that what is happening?

However, if the radio signal has good strength, the coil is not doing a good job.
Is there any other better solution that I can achieve blocking/unblocking with electrical/electronics (without mechanical parts)?

Comment: Placed a flat tightly woven wire *where*, and in what orientation?

Comment: Between the two antennas (like a sandwich).